# CPLEX cannot extract the expression

Tags: expression, extract, default, cplex, cannot-find-symbol

program-EV Charge Scheduling
error

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CPLEX(default) cannot extract expression: forall(i in 0..11, j in 0..4) if ( soc[i][j] > 0.7 ) pevch[i][j] == soc[i][j]*100000; else true.  model.mod   /singlebus  36:1-38:33 E:\Haripriya\cplexoutput\singlebus\model.mod OPL Problem Marker
Program

```
 range t=0..11;
 range n=0..4;
 int j=0;
//forcasted load at 0..4
float pl[t]=[10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000];
//soc of ev at 0..11
float soc[n][t] =      [[0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.75,0.85,0.95],
                        [0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.75,0.85,0.95],
                        [0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.75,0.85,0.95],
                        [0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.75,0.85,0.95],
                        [0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.75,0.85,0.95]];
//generation
float pg[t]=[10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000,10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000];
//target load at 0..11
float pt[t]=[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000];
//bus voltage at 0..11
float v[t]=[5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,5,4];
//bus voltage at 
// target bus voltage at 0..11
float vt[t]=[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4];
//decision variable charging power ev
dvar float pevch[t][n];

//decision variable discharging power of ev
dvar float pevdis[t][n];

//objective function
minimize sum(i in t)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in n)-pevch[i][j]+sum(j in n)pevdis[i][j]);
subject to
{ 
forall(i in t, j in n)
  if(soc[i][j]>0.7)
  pevch[i][j]==soc[i][j]*100000;
 }
```

Solution to tackle this error

Answer (score 0):

You may have mixed i and j

If you write

```
subject to
{ 
forall(i in t, j in n)
  if(soc[j][i]>0.7)
  pevch[i][j]==soc[j][i]*100000;
 }
```

then your model works fine

Comment: Sir, thankyou for your effort.The error in my program is gone. But there is no solution shown.

Comment: If you set bounds you will get a solution dvar float+ pevch[t][n] in 0..100000 ;
dvar float+ pevdis[t][n] in 0..100000;